# Loop to check dupilicate random strings

Tags: php

I have this function which creates random string:

```
function genID($length) {
    $chars = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM@!"; 
    //only allowed chars in the blowfish salt.
    $size = strlen($chars); $str = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        $str .= $chars[rand(0, $size - 1)]; // strings can be used as char arrays
        // Yes, I am aware this salt isn't generated using the OS source.
        // use mycrypt_create_iv or /dev/urandom/
    return $str;
}
```

This output something like:

```
@iBUQvldLq
```

Now I have users list with something like that:

```
  userid    |   username   |  usermail ...
--------------------------------------
@iBUQvldLq        test      test@gmaik.com ....
```

Now when some one register I create new string and insert the new string to `userid` row in database, after that I create a new string, then I check if the new string created doesn't exist, something like this:

```
function newID()
{

     $newid = genID(10);
     $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '".$newid."'";
     $result1 = mysql_query($query);
     $num = mysql_num_rows($result1);
     if($num == 1)
     {
         $newid = genID(10);
         return $newid;
     }
     else
     {
         return $newid;
     }
}
```

Any one have any idea how to loop on the check function?

I mean the generate function create new random string, then the function check if it already exist, then create new one, if not return the one created.

So now if he create new one, and the new one also match the same other `userid`, so how I loop until the new string won't match never to other `userid` string?

Something like loop:

1. create new string
2. verify if exist
3. if exist create new one
4. if the new one also exist create new one and so on

Till its never match other `userid`, make a loop, any idea ?

EDITED :

The new function for loop if any need:

function newID(){

```
   $continue = true;

   while ($continue) {
   $newid = genID(10);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='".$newid."' LIMIT 1");

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1)
    $continue = false;
    return $newid;
}
```

}

```
$newid = newID();
```

Comment: use an uto-incremented id (primary or unique key) from the db, no checking needed,

Comment: Sorry but why do you want to generate a random userid instead of using auto increment? Also if you want it to be random why not simple use something like `MD5(uniqid())` on a unique field type

Comment: Its more secure then auto-incremented. better using my way , Anway i dont have problem with my string create..

Comment: Define SECURE. What is your worry against the auto increment or that makes you think you need a random userid like that?

Comment: Its harder to guess user id , wont be nice if you get in to ebay and doing user.php?showprofile=1 and u see the first user registerd on ebay u dont agree ?

Comment: if any one can see the users anyway, what's the problem? they are linked? they are indexed? they are accessible vai google, what's the problem?

Comment: @asdasdasda You don't need to display the auto incremental userid, you can easily display the username just like ebay does?

Comment: Anyway i need to keep random strings , for harder guessing , i can make it domain.com/users/test , but if there is a hacker or bot or somthing he can see that behind that its users.php?profile=1 so i prefer to make my way..

Comment: no you don't, you just don't know any better. And refuse to accept tha advise of others

Comment: Hmm i had a question if some one know how to loop the function and not how to make it other way.. this way working my site ...

Comment: `he can see that behind that its users.php?profile=1` same goes with your current random user id. It does not matter if its sequential or not if its available on your site with a bot he can just crawl it.

Comment: your user page on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2781365/asdasd-asda the next user http://stackoverflow.com/users/2781366 etc so what ?

Comment: I still prefer using random string because people cant know how much registerd users have , more secure and so on...

Comment: its simply not more 'secure' in any sense of the word

Comment: Here is your logic, basically you're saying you will have a userid and a username field which both are unique, you will have the overhead of looping to find a free userid on every registration it may be nothing for 1000 users database but its a lot on a 1m+ users database, then you tell me your worry is about people being able to get all users via `users.php?profile=1` then why don't you just use `users.php?profile=username` instead since username is unique? This way you can use the incremental id without having any worry of it being misused by some one else.

Comment: OK , thanks i'v edited with working code .. if anyone needed.

Comment: And in either way a bot can easily crawl your website for unique user id or usernames and get the amount of users you have you're just not making any sense, your trying to secure your website by making it use more resources in exchange of no security.

Comment: Ok .. this way my site working , even my pages using random id's this way i prefer .. Thanks for help :).

Comment: and for more pointless code, you have `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` after the select, inside a loop, do you know what this is even for?

Comment: afcours :/ its was there because i had other function before , i'v edited my question and cleared and fix the code's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your wanting code like this..

```
function uHash(){
    $continue = true;
    while ($continue) {
        $hash = substr(MD5(microtime()), 0, 7);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT `Link` FROM Table WHERE `value`='$hash' LIMIT 1");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1)
            $continue = false;

        return $hash;
    }
}
```

The script will loop until it finds a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your **`user_id`** column as an **`auto_increment`** field would solve this issue. [Best Approach]

If you really want to do with PHP, couple **`uniqid()`** with **`rand()`** to generate a unique seed that doesn't collide.

Something like this

```
<?php
echo $id = uniqid(rand(), true);
?>
```

Comment: auto_increment making somthing like this : 1,2,3,4,5,6, . random string making more secure to guess other userid , about the function mine function have no problem i just want to make 100% check that there is no duplicate users id's..

Comment: They both working almost the same , just uniqid its php ready function , and mine its write regular.. anyway i will keep waiting somone know how to loop the newid until there is no duplicate one

Answer (score 0):

Just you can use for unique id

```
<?php

function genID() {
    return uniqid();
}

echo genID();

?>
```